# Call to a member function Error

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-gateway

I am getting below **error** when I am **redirected from payment gateway** to merchant page. Tried to google for solution but din't find any solution for this.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean
>   in
>   /home/website/public_html/website/homedir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php
>   on line 119

```
public function getInfoBlock(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $info)
{
    $blockType = $info->getMethodInstance()->getInfoBlockType();
    if ($this->getLayout()) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($blockType);
    }
    else {
        $className = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($blockType);
        $block = new $className;
    }
    $block->setInfo($info);
    return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling **getMethodInstance** function somewhere in your code where your object is returning false.

You have to set if condition there.
Suppose your object variable is **$payment**, then you have to set the if condition as given below

```
if ($payment->getMethodInstance()) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: i not sure how it been called, i have edit the question with the existing code,Can you go through and help me out